# Values from widget classes (e.g. dropdown) using python and kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to use the value selected in a dropdown menu elsewhere in the code, specifically to populate MyData class.

Some background: my original question of how to get the buttons to work was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60385318/instantiate-data-class-from-dropdown-menu-options-using-on-touch-up) (thanks). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280855/kivy-drop-down-list-how-to-get-current-text-from-selected-button) answer shows how to print the value when it is selected. However, I cannot seem to access or print the selection anywhere other than the `on_release=lambda btn: print(btn.text)` statement.

The following code has some simple print statements to show the values I am trying to track. The comments above explain the output.

My main questions are:

1) Why are the default pos values printed every time MyPopup is called? (Note: the values I pass when calling MyPopup are printed immediately after.)

2) How do I get the color choice from MyColor?

3) What exactly does 'self.drop.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self, 'text', x))' do? If it sets 'self.text' to the selection, how do I access that value (note: 'self.text' does not give me the color).

4) How do I get pos and color into MyData?

The .py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.factory import Factory

class AddTouch(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddTouch, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5, mode="rgba")
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(10, 10))
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.rect.pos = touch.pos
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.rect.pos = touch.pos
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        # final position
        self.rect.pos = touch.pos
        MyPopup(pos=touch.pos)


class MyPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, pos=[0,0]):
        super(MyPopup, self).__init__(pos=[0,0])
        self.pos = pos
        self.title = 'Select Color'
        self.color = MyColor.text
        # when MyPopup is called this first prints:
        #   from MyPopup [0, 0], <StringProperty name=text>
        # then immediately prints (for example)
        #   from MyPopup [758.0, 500.0], <StringProperty name=text>
        print('from MyPopup {}, {}'.format(self.pos, self.color))

    def save(self):
        # when save button is clicked this prints:
        #    from MyPopup.save [0, 0], <StringProperty name=text>
        print('from MyPopup.save {}, {}'.format(self.pos,self.color))
        MyData(self.pos, self.color)


class MyColor(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyColor, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.drop = DropDown()
        colorlist = ['black', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', 'white']
        for index in colorlist:
            btn = Button(text='%s' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.drop.select(btn.text))
            self.drop.add_widget(btn)
        self.bind(on_release=self.drop.open)
        # I thought this would 'setattr' of self.text to the selected value
        self.drop.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self, 'text', x))

class MyData:
    def __init__(self, pos,color):
        # this prints :
        #    from MyData [0, 0], <StringProperty name=text>
        print('from MyData {}, {}'.format(pos,color))

# using kivy screen for consistency
class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv = Builder.load_file("dropdown.kv")
class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

The .kv:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    AddTouch:
        on_touch_up:
            Factory.MyPopup().open()

<MyPopup>:
    text:'Enter Data'
    auto_dismiss: False
    FloatLayout:
        MyColor:
            text: 'Value'
            size_hint: 1,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x": 0,"top":1}
        Button:
            text: 'Save'
            size_hint: 1,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x": 0,"top":0.5}
            on_press: root.save()
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter your subwidgets by using id's:

```
<MyPopup>:
    text:'Enter Data'
    auto_dismiss: False
    FloatLayout:
        MyColor:
            id: MyColor
            text: 'Value'
            size_hint: 1,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x": 0,"top":1}
        Button:
            id: Button1
            text: 'Save'
            size_hint: 1,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x": 0,"top":0.5}
            on_press: root.save()
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

and now in your .py file you can access the widgets like this:

```
class MyPopup(Popup):
    def some_function(self):
        print(self.ids.Button1.text)
        print(self.ids.MyColor.size_hint)
```

alternative syntax:

```
print(self.ids["Button1"].text)
```